# Выборка определенных строк MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Например в таблице есть 10 строк. Нужно выбрать записи с 4 по 7. Как сделать и вообще можно ли так ? 
По ID не получится так как id может начинаться не с 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 3, 3
```

Где первое число 3 - смещение, второе 3 - количество.

http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/SELECT.html

Comment: да думал через OFFSET оказывается есть запрос ещё корое